# Completely remove separators using slugify

Tags: php, slug, separator, slugify

I am using [slugify](https://github.com/cocur/slugify) to generate the users slug but I want to remove dashes, dots, spaces and every type character that would be considered a separator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible changing the default separator to an empty string, so this:

```
echo $slugify->slugify('A strange.example_user-name', '');
```

Will return this:

```
astrangeexampleusername
```